# Concat two tensors

Tags: pytorch, concatenation, tensor

I want to concat two tensors of size `a: torch.Size([16, 1])` and `b: torch.Size([16, 120])`
to be of size `torch.Size([16, 121])`

could you please help with that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concat tensors in PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54727686/concat-tensors-in-pytorch)

Comment: Not really, I tried it but didn't work with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use the `torch.cat()` function.

Example:

```
>>> a = torch.rand([16,1])
>>> b = torch.rand([16,120])
>>> a.size()
torch.Size([16, 1])
>>> b.size()
torch.Size([16, 120])
>>> c = torch.cat((a,b),dim=1)
>>> c.size()
torch.Size([16, 121])
```

What you want to do is to concatenate the tensors on the first dimension (`dim=1`).

Comment: What if I want the resulted tensor to be torch.Size([16, 1])?

Comment: @LamaMo what is your purpose?

Comment: @LamaMo, what are the two tensors signifying? What do you want the resulting tensor to signify. I think that would decide how to go about it.